# How to optimize SQL delete query with subselect for Firebird?

Tags: sql, query-optimization, firebird, sql-delete, firebird-3.0

The following query is extremely slow. It seems the subselect is executed for each row in the table?!

```
delete from HISTORY
where ID in (
  select ID from (
    select ID, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by SOURCE order by ID desc) as NUM from HISTORY
  ) where NUM > 100
);
```

This is a cleanup query. It should delete everything but the 100 most recent records per `SOURCE`.

The time required seems to depend only on the number of records in the table and not on how many records are to be deleted. Even with only 10,000 records it takes several minutes. However, if I only execute the sub-select, it is fast.

Of course there is a PK on `ID` and a FK and index on `SOURCE` (both are Integer columns).

Comment: `> the subselect is executed for each row in the table?!` Exactly. Maybe get some ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906720/obtaining-one-value-per-person-from-table-latest-n-per-group-before-cutoff-dat

Comment: you can use IDE like IBExpert to check statistics about query execution, for example how many Cache Fetches and Disk Fetches there were, that way you would verify your idea about linear scaling per rows count :-)

Comment: as a rule of thumb when you see `in` (and especially `not in`) in interbase/firebird try to check if you can easily reforumlate query into something else. It is not always bad, but often enough to train that habit.

Comment: Do I remember correctly that many other database systems do this much better and would have no problem with it?

Comment: Maybe. But Interbase/Firebird from conceiption was oriented to be low-cost engine, both in maintenance (no dedicated DBA, instant DB restarting after hard crashes) and code size and footprint addded to applications operating. On one hand it has little query restructuring, on another it has higher predictability and potentially less bugs in SQL optimizer. Of majors RBMS systems i guess only SQLite can compare to FB/IB with "little footprint" metrics. Of course it can not feature-match systems that are 100 times larger code-wise and team-wise.

Comment: About re-executing subqueries there is also that idea, that it can not be claimed invarient, as query results are `volatile variables` in C++ terms, their value can be be changed "inside the loop". For example, in read-commited transactions - by commiting some another tx. And before FB3 even from the same query (`insert into TableName select * from TableName` run infinitely until meeting error (PK violations, out of disk volume, out of int32 for ID, etc), see cursor stability at https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/bk02ch09s06.html#rnfb30-dml-altquoting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird 3 added `DELETE` option into `MERGE` clause. It was first mentioned in [Release Notes](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-dml-merge.html). It is now properly documented in [Firebird 3 SQL Reference](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-dml-merge).

Modelling by the examples there the cleanup query would look like that:

```
merge into HISTORY HDel
using ( select ID, SOURCE, ROW_NUMBER() over
                (partition by SOURCE order by ID desc) as NUM 
        from HISTORY ) HVal
   on (HVal.NUM > 100) and (HVal.ID = HDel.ID) and (HVal.Source = HDel.Source)
WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE
```

In your specific database `(HVal.Source = HDel.Source)` filtering seems  redundant, but i still decided to add it to make the query as generic as possibe, for future readers. Better safe than sorry :-)

---

Firebird 2.x did not provide for that feature, and with FB3's MERGE/DELETE and Window Functions features missing one can fall back to explicit imperative programming and write good old loops. It would take writing and executing a small PSQL program (either a persistent named Stored Procedure or ad hoc `EXECUTE BLOCK` statement) with making explicit loop over `SOURCE` values.

Something like (i did not syntax-check it, just scratching from memory):

```
execute block as
declare variable SRC_VAL integer;
declare variable ID_VAL integer;
begin
  for select distinct SOURCE from HISTORY into :SRC_VAL do begin
     :ID_VAL = NULL;
     select first(1) skip(100) ID from HISTORY
       where SOURCE = :SRC_VAL
       order by ID desc
       into :ID_VAL;
     if (:ID_VAL IS NOT NULL) then
       delete from HISTORY 
         where SOURCE = :SRC_VAL 
           and ID <= :ID_VAL;
  end
end
```

Comment: Here is some english documentation: https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-dml-merge.html

Comment: Great, I tested the merge query and it works as it is and it is fast! (I just removed `SOURCE` from the columns returned by the subselect and from the on-condition - because ID is already unique in my case)

Comment: The English `MERGE` documentation for Firebird 3 can be found at https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-dml-merge